# What is the comma doing here?

Tags: python

Hi I have a simple code:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print '\b*'
```

outputs:

```
*

*

*

*

*

*

*

*

* 

*
```

however when I add a comma at the end like so:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    print '\b*' ,
```

Output is:

```
**********
```

What exactly is the comma doing here with respect to \b??

Comment: `print x` means output `x` and then a new-line. `print x,` means output `x` and then a space.

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/)? The [section about the `print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) might be useful.

Comment: The result isn't apparent from your example?

Comment: @khelwood Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)

> A '\n' character is written at the end,
>   unless the print statement ends with a comma.